Prevent port scanning on OpenWRT
Imagine you need to have open ports on your Internet router but you don't want them to be easily discovered or enumerated.
How can you prevent hackers/companies from scanning your open ports?


Edit your /etc/config/firewall and add this:

config include
    option enabled '1'
    option type 'script'
    option path '/etc/firewall.user'
    option fw4_compatible '1'


Create the file /etc/firewall.user containing this:

set -x # enable verbose mode

nft add set inet fw4 scanner { type ipv4_addr\; flags timeout\; timeout 24h\; }

nft add set inet fw4 good { type inet_service\; elements = { \
    5000, \
    10000 \
}}

nft add set inet fw4 known { type ipv4_addr\; flags constant, interval\; elements = { \
    35.203.210.0/24,  \
    35.203.211.0/24,  \
    45.128.232.0/24,  \
    64.62.156.0/24,   \
    64.62.197.0/24,   \
    65.49.1.0/24,     \
    94.156.71.0/24,   \
    107.170.0.0/16,   \
    123.254.109.0/24, \
    152.32.128.0/17,  \
    162.142.125.0/24, \
    162.216.149.0/24, \
    162.216.150.0/24, \
    162.243.0.0/16,   \
    167.94.138.0/24,  \
    167.94.145.0/24,  \
    167.94.146.0/24,  \
    185.180.143.0/24, \
    185.242.226.0/24, \
    192.241.128.0/17, \
    193.163.125.0/24, \
    198.235.24.0/24,  \
    198.199.96.0/20,  \
    199.45.154.0/24,  \
    206.168.32.0/22,  \
    205.210.31.0/24   \
}}

nft insert rule inet fw4 input_wan ip  saddr @scanner counter log drop
nft insert rule inet fw4 input_wan tcp dport \!= @good ct state new tcp flags \& \(fin\|syn\|rst\|ack\) == syn update @scanner { ip saddr }
nft insert rule inet fw4 input_wan ip  saddr @scanner update @scanner { ip saddr }

nft insert rule inet fw4 prerouting ip saddr @scanner counter log drop
nft insert rule inet fw4 prerouting ip saddr @known  counter drop


Mark the user firewall script executable: chmod +x /etc/firewall.user

You can now apply the rules: fw4 restart.


Explanatory notes

The @scanner set contains the IPs that have tried to open any ports other than @good which is a list of ports you want to keep open for all hosts regardless. It has an expiration time of 24 hours because my WiFi router is quite old and feeble and cannot have and process fast enough too many records in this set. You can change 24h to something like 7d. Suit yourself.
The @known set is what I've collected over a week or so, these are the networks that do port scanning all the time.
This is tested against OpenWRT 23.xx only. It may not work in future releases.

Important information

This whole ruleset is redundant if you open ports only to whitelisted IP addresses but sometimes you travel and need to access your home network from unknown locations thus this ruleset.
Another solution would be to enable port knocking but using this technique on e.g. your smartphone is not always trivial or possible especially if you need to forward ports to your LAN for other non tech-savvy people.


Sorry for negative comment but your code is 1.) not efficient because whitelisted addresses might as well be zombies and 2.) covers only TCP, see my approach here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/345114/how-to-protect-against-port-scanners/774404#774404

Understandable, but then you might want to remove udp tag from your question. interesting fact btw. is that there is no solution for udp though anywhere on the net ;)


It works perfectly on several OpenWRT devices 2. It's written specifically for OpenWRT while yours is a brand new incompatible policy 3. I don't care about UDP. In fact I don't even want to process UDP because it's an additional load on the CPU 4. I'm not sure what you mean by "zombies". I don't want scanning from anything trying to connect to my WRT devices. 5. It's super efficient as it blocks on a first "wrong" port connection attempt at which point the IP is blacklisted for 24 hours. 6. I've removed UDP, here you're correct. Modifying it for UDP is super-trivial.


By "zombies" I mean that you block entire IP blocks but not all of them might be needed to be blocked thus blocking legitimate clients, see what is zombie https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_(computing)

"The @known set is what I've collected over a week or so, these are the networks that do port scanning all the time." - it's completely arbitrary and may or may not be used.
